# Generate unordered pairs from list in perl

Tags: perl

Perl newbie here.

I want to loop over pairs of words, coming from a list of words:

```
 @words = ("word1", "word2", "word3", "word4");
```

I want to create and process all pairs of words, but *pair ordering is not important*, i.e. the pairs 
`("word1", "word2")` and `("word2, "word1")` are considered the same and only one of them should be generated.

Is there an easy way to do this? The obvious solution would be to have an nested loop somewhat like:

```
for my $i1 (0 ... $#words) {
    for my $i2 ($i1 + 1 ... $#words) {
        process_pair(words[$i1], words[$i2])
    }
}
```

but I am looking for something more Perl-esque than this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed R=2, the solution you presented is quite appropriate.

```
for my $i1 (0 ... $#words) {
   for my $i2 ($i1 + 1 ... $#words) {
      process_pair($words[$i1], $words[$i2])
   }
}
```

But what if R was larger or variable? You can do some powerful stuff using `NestedLoops`.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $R = 2;

NestedLoops(
   [  [ 0..$#words ],
      ( sub { [$_+1..$#words] } ) x ($R-1),
   ],
   \&process_pair,
);
```

Or as an iterator

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $R = 2;

my $iter = NestedLoops([
   [ 0..$#words ],
   ( sub { [$_+1..$#words] } ) x ($R-1),
]);

while (my @combo = $iter->()) {
    process_pair(@combo);
}
```

But that's hardly readable. Solutions that specifically address this problem are going to be cleanest.

```
use Math::Combinatorics qw( );

my $R = 2;

my $iter = Math::Combinatorics->new( count => $R, data => \@words );
while (my @combo = $iter->next_combination) {
    process_pair(@combo);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was unaware that Algorithms had such methods. Very nice!